# C# How to run exe in PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I want to run mc.exe using by PowerShell as I write below.

How can I do that? I tried to add in Filename but it doesn't work.

```
var mcExe = @"C:\Users\developer\Desktop\Example\mc.exe ";

var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = mcExe;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "./mc alias set myCloud http://localhost:9000", "admin", "123456");
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Could you check if the proc is running and print the ExitCode if the proc has exited ?

Comment: I changed there is no error but doesn't executing, Arguments = @"@('cd C:\Users\developer\Desktop\Example\', './mc alias set myCloud http://localhost:9000', 'admin', '12345678', './mc admin user add myCloud testwashere 12345678')",

Answer (score 1):

Did you try set `proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` ?
Because this property responsible for using powershell

Answer (score 1):

Starting Powershell directly might work for you, e.g. :

```
using System.Diagnostics;

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"powershell.exe",
    Arguments = @"& 'C:\Users\developer\Desktop\Example\mc.exe' @('./mc alias set myCloud http://localhost:9000', 'admin', '123456')",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "runas",
};
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

string errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping but I got same error like below : "mc.exe: <ERROR> `./mc alias set myCloud http://localhost:9000` is not a recognized command.

Comment: could you provide that script? so we can try it on our local?

Comment: when i wrote  ./mc alias set myCloud http://localhost:9000 that in powershell there is no problem its working fine. but when we tried to work in c# we are getting error

Comment: With your code which you send me, proc is working. But I did not understand why saying is not a recognized command.

Comment: yeah, not sure, without having the script it's hard to guess what's wrong...

Comment: actually, I can directly to the scripting file using by cd, for example: cd C:\Users\developer\Desktop\Example\, and then invoke other commands. It could be very good this way, any suggestions?

Comment: ehm, I don't think you have a way to do that unfortunately